# C 2 Dimensional Char in Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char, variable-assignment

i'm trying to read input into a 2dim char struct member,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { HIGHT=14, WIDTH=147, IMAGES=24 };

typedef struct{
    char *frame[HIGHT][WIDTH];
    int fps;
} frame_stack_t;

void out(frame_stack_t *frame_stack[IMAGES]);

int main(){
    frame_stack_t *frame_stack[IMAGES];

    for (int i=0; i<IMAGES; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<HIGHT; j++){
            strcpy( frame_stack[i]->frame[j], "some text" );
        }
    }

    out(frame_stack);
}

void out(frame_stack_t *frame_stack[IMAGES]){
    for (int i=0; i<IMAGES; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<HIGHT; j++){
            printf("%s",frame_stack[i]->frame[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

It look right to me, but I recive the following output:

```
test_struct.c: In function ‘main’:
test_struct.c:19:25: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    strcpy( "some text", frame_stack[i]->frame[j] );
                         ^
In file included from test_struct.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:125:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^
test_struct.c: In function ‘out’:
test_struct.c:29:11: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("%s",frame_stack[i]->frame[j]);
           ^
Speicherzugriffsfehler
```

with gdb telling me that strcpy failed

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:546
546 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: You have an array of char pointer arrays. Indexing the array will give you a char pointer array, not char pointer

Comment: please do at least SOME manual reading before asking questions. Eg, your `strcpy()` arguments are the wrong way around

Comment: thx mixed that up again, I posted the new error.

Answer (score 0):

The C code in question has so many problems. Please do some reading and practice before posting question to open forum like this. See the below corrected code and try to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { HIGHT=14, IMAGES=24, WIDTH=147 };

typedef struct{
char frame[HIGHT][WIDTH];
int fps;
} frame_stack_t;

void out(frame_stack_t *frame_stack);

int main()
{
frame_stack_t frame_stack[IMAGES];
int i, j;

for (i=0; i<IMAGES; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<HIGHT; j++)
    {
        strcpy(frame_stack[i].frame[j], "some text\n" );
    }
}

out(frame_stack);
}

void out(frame_stack_t frame_stack[])
{
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<IMAGES; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<HIGHT; j++)
    {
        printf("%s",frame_stack[i].frame[j]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which Problems do you mean? Beside the one described Problem I posted the code is running fine.